# What does this elaborate output script mean?

Tags: transactions, script

Bitcoin transaction [a214a2daf91691afdd491fd00d894eb3301e35bc18b5554b14e12843037e954c](https://blockchain.info/tx-index/42766264/0) has an interesting output script:

> PUSHDATA(33)[02085c6600657566acc2d6382a47bc3f324008d2aa10940dd7705a48aa2a5a5e33] CHECKSIG SWAP PUSHDATA(33)[03f5d0fb955f95dd6be6115ce85661db412ec6a08abcbfce7da0ba8297c6cc0ec4] CHECKSIG SWAP 3 PICK SHA256 PUSHDATA(32)[d68df9e32a147cffa36193c6f7c43a1c8c69cda530e1c6db354bfabdcfefaf3c] EQUAL 3 PICK SHA256 PUSHDATA(32)[f531f3041d3136701ea09067c53e7159c8f9b2746a56c3d82966c54bbc553226] EQUAL BOOLAND 4 PICK SIZE NIP PUSHDATA(1)[20] PUSHDATA(1)[22] WITHIN BOOLAND 3 PICK SIZE NIP PUSHDATA(1)[20] PUSHDATA(1)[22] WITHIN BOOLAND IF 3 PICK SIZE NIP 3 PICK SIZE NIP EQUAL PICK ELSE BOOLAND ENDIF

I'm very curious what this means. It is not a standard transaction type and therefore it does not have an address.

This [output is redeemed](https://blockchain.info/tx/e280770f2fdb32ca1b04949e67a211e114c0927f50846b89ab3a78b3e4c469c8) using two signatures:

> ScriptSig: 0[] 0[] PUSHDATA(72)[30450221009a29101094b283ae62a6fed68603c554ca3a624b9a78d83e8065edcf97ae231b02202cbed6e796ee6f4caf30edef8f5597a08a6be265d6601ad92283990b55c038fa01] PUSHDATA(71)[3044022045d08719828fbd93e49c9223e63f4d2dab2de6c568e1faa2cccb33adf2575d2c02200c00126cb0105275040a963d91e45460147e40451b590485cf438606d3c784cf01]

What does this output script mean?

Comment: I have last recently answered to a very similar script. basically it is early "multisig" trials, which is nowadays with P2SH much more easy. Basically the script can be easily decoded and explained, one would just have to have an idea how data behaves on the stack (FORTH like).